# Mockito and Powermock cannot mock ClassLoader

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following instruction in Java:

```
 String path = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getPath();
```

I need to mock the `ClassLoader` returned by `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()`, using Mockito and Powermock.

I tried with this:

```
@Mock ClassLoader classLoader;

whenNew(ClassLoader.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(classLoader);
```

But it doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: "I need to mock the ClassLoader returned by ...". No you don't. You need to change your design.

Comment: What would you change?

Comment: That depends on what your code does. But probably you will want to introduce an additional level of abstraction. In the easiest case, reference the class you are trying to hack through an interface, and pass in a mock for that. Obey the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Comment: But in this way I will still need a test for the additional level of abstraction that access the class loader. so, the problem doesn't change

Answer (score 3):

As the comments indicate: you are approaching this on the wrong level.

Looking at your code:

```
String path = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getPath();
```

You see, the `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName)` part; that is "built-in" technology.

What I mean is: unless other parts of your code mess around with the ClassLoader, then the above does exactly what it is supposed to do. There is absolutely no need to test that extensively. You only care about: here class, and file name; something give me a Path. **That** is what matters to you. Thus: **abstract** that!

In other words: you just go forward and **add** that additional abstraction, like:

```
public interface PathProvider {
   public Path getPathFromUrl(Class<?> clazz);
}
```

A simple implementation could look like

```
public class PathProviderImpl implements PathProvider {
   @Override
   Path getPathFromUrl(Class<?> clazz, String fileName) {
     return clazz.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getPath();
}
```

or something alike. Please note: you can write a simple unit test that checks this implementation, too.

But the core point is: instead of making the **static** call within your production code, you use a (mocked) instance of that interface.

No need for PowerMock, no need for static mocking; just nice, plain mockito stuff!

Besides: the above **fixes** your design problem. You created **hard to test** production code; and you don't fix that by using the big PowerMock hammer; you fix it *improving* the bad design.

Comment: but the PathProvider method has two parameters for the sake of testing, when it could have only one. What's wrong with that? It would just be getPathFromUrl(String fileName)  So, does it mean I'm complicating the interface, for the sake of testing?

Comment: That was just an example. Of course you could change the whole things o that the IMPL class takes a file name (or the class) with its constructor - then you don't need to put that into the "interface" method. Don't expect full blown correct solutions here - this is meant as inspiration to make you aware of *other* options. An answer doesn't mean that all work is done. To the contrary ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking a new Statement, but you have not any new statement in your Code

As for my understanding, you should:

- Mock static MyClass
- Mock getClassLoader()
- create a mock for ClassLoader
- mock method getResource

Something as follows:

```
@Mock ClassLoader classLoader;

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClass.class);
    BDDMockito.given(MyClass.getClassLoader()).willReturn(classLoader);
    PowerMockito.doReturn("desiredResource").when(classLoader).getResource(Mockito.anyString());
```

Also you may need to set at the beginning of your test class the following lines:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockListener(AnnotationEnabler.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
public class yourTestClass....
```